# Ansible: difference between "shell" and "command" modules

Tags: linux, ansible

Ansible wiki [says](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html):

*The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like `<`, `>`, `|`, `;` and `&` will not work (use the shell module if you need these features).*

But there is no difference between them in Ansible:

```
[oracle@temp ansible]$ ansible temp2 -m shell -a "ls -la $HOME"
temp2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
total 40
drwx------. 6 oracle dba   4096 May 16 15:31 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root    20 Mar 18 18:45 ..
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     17 May 16 15:31 .ansible
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba   8100 Apr 17 12:50 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba     18 Aug 24  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba    257 Mar 19 10:53 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba    231 Aug 24  2018 .bashrc
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     16 Mar 22 12:19 .cache
drwx------. 4 oracle dba     28 Mar 22 12:19 .config
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     19 Mar 22 12:19 .local
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba  10425 Apr 16 14:50 .psql_history
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba    713 Mar 19 11:15 .viminfo

[oracle@temp ansible]$ ansible temp2 -m command -a "ls -la $HOME"
temp2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
total 40
drwx------. 6 oracle dba   4096 May 16 15:31 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root    20 Mar 18 18:45 ..
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     17 May 16 15:31 .ansible
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba   8100 Apr 17 12:50 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba     18 Aug 24  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba    257 Mar 19 10:53 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba    231 Aug 24  2018 .bashrc
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     16 Mar 22 12:19 .cache
drwx------. 4 oracle dba     28 Mar 22 12:19 .config
drwx------. 3 oracle dba     19 Mar 22 12:19 .local
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba  10425 Apr 16 14:50 .psql_history
-rw-------. 1 oracle dba    713 Mar 19 11:15 .viminfo
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 8):

You're passing the parameter in double quotes. `$HOME` is expanded by the shell on your local machine, ansible doesn't even get to see it. If you use single quotes instead, you should be able to see a difference. (You would also have noticed if the path didn't exist on the remote machine.)

Answer (score 0):

From [ansible-lint](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/) documentation for the [command-instead-of-shell](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/command-instead-of-shell/) rule.

> This rule identifies uses of `shell` modules instead of a `command` one when this is not really needed. Shell is considerably slower than command and should be avoided unless there is a special need for using shell features, like environment variable expansion or chaining multiple commands using pipes.