# Execute command using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to use the `dpkg -l | grep -i staff` command using ansible, but it gives me an error:

```
ansible all -m 'dpkj -l | grep -i stuff' 


ERROR! this task 'dpkj' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, win_command, shell, win_shell, script, include, include_vars, include_tasks, include_role, import_tasks, import_role, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta
```

then I made playbook for it:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible command
    command: dpkg -l | grep -i staff
```

and it gives me an error again:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["dpkg", "-l", "|", "grep", "-i", "staff"], "delta": "0:00:00.010754", "end": "2019-06-26 18:15:10.373642", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-06-26 18:15:10.362888", "stderr": "dpkg-query: no packages found matching |\ndpkg-query: no packages found matching -i\ndpkg-query: no packages found matching stuff"
```

How can I execute this command using ansible?

Comment: Looks like a simple typo in the first command :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a pipe in a simple command; [Ansible: difference between "shell" and "command" modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519290/ansible-difference-between-shell-and-command-modules) mentions the Ansible documentation for the `command` module:

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like `<`, `>`, `|`, `;` and `&` will not work. **Use the shell module if you need these features.**

Notice the `|` symbol in that list of operations that "will not work".

Comment: ok, I delete '| grep -i stuff' and it working fine,but how can I see the output of 'dpkg' command

Comment: and is it possible to use 'grep' some how?

Comment: did you change the playbook to use `shell` instead of `command`?

Comment: thanks,I used shell, and 'dpkj -l | grep -i stuff' work great, but where I can see the output of this command?

Comment: That seems to be a common question (at least, on Stack Overflow); it appears you need to use a `register` directive to assign the output to a variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563639/ansible-playbook-shell-output for some examples.

Comment: Since we got the command executed, you might consider this question asked & answered, and open a new question with your updated playbook and question about capturing output (including how you want it displayed & when).